# JSON.parse() function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, json, simplejson

I have a list that i am trying to parse to a `json object, ["Harry ", "Potter ", "Name ", "Batman"]`. I am using Django templates for this. I have parsed the list using `simplejson.dumps()`.
I am trying to parse this in my javascript code.It is working fine until the line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;` in my code, it is printing `["Harry ", "Potter ", "Name ", "Batman"]` correctly.but `JSON.parse()` is not working.The lines written after calling parse are not working. Can anyone tell me the problem with this code?

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block content%}

<p id="demo">hai {{y}} im</p>

<script>

var x = (("{{y}}").replace(/&(l|g|quo)t;/g, function(a,b){
               return {
                   l   : '<',
                   g   : '>',
                   quo : '"'
               }[b];
           }));
x = x.replace(/u'/g, '\'');
x = x.replace(/'/g, '\"');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
p = JSON.parse( x );
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Aray";
</script>
{%endblock%}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is all that conversion logic for? Why don't you output correct json from your view in  the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to **stringify** it before you parse it. Look at the example below:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var str = JSON.stringify(arr);
document.write(str);
document.write ("<br/>");

var newArr = JSON.parse(str);
```